# How can I limit the size of an individual field for an apache log?

Tags: logging, apache2

**History/Explanation**: I am using apache2 on a Linux server. The logs are becoming huge (11 Meg an hour roughly).

**Problem**: Referring URL's within the site can be up to about 3kb in size.  (I know it is bad... I didn't make them.) A lot of parameters are passed via the GET method.

**Needed**: 
Is there a way to truncate the just the referrer field for the apache access log?
Is there a way to just show the TLD of the referrer in the apache access log?

I know I can create a custom "access" log, and just not include the referrer, however I want to track the TLD (Top Level Domain) of incoming traffic.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the TLD of the referrer you're interested in, you can use ([mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) to pick it out and put it in an environment variable, which you can then print in your log file.